# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced when using Dlib in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, lnk2019, dlib

I'm using Dlib 19.3 in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015. For compiling, I create Win32 Console Application, empty project. From Source Files, I add Existing Item file Source.cpp from *dlib-19.3\dlib\all*

Right-click on project *properties*, at *Configuration* choose *All Configurations*, then, on *C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories*, I click on *Edit* and paste link to my dlib-19.3 folder, then I click OK.

I compile it and I get the following error

> MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

How can I fix it?

[Screen capture error LNK2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u49ti.png)

Comment: having only Source.cpp is not enough. you should write your code that will use dlib. for example - try adding one more .cpp file from examples folder

Comment: @Evgeniy Thanks, It work. But one more question, do I need to use Cmake for Dlib or I just add Dlib folder path to my project?

Comment: both ways works. if you don't understand this - better to use Source.cpp included into your project